# Possible reasons for failure http connection between two servers?

Tags: php, apache, sockets, http, server

I have 3 shared hosting servers, server 1, server 2 and server 3
server 1 and 2 both run the same php version 5.6,

The following script checks if server 3 is reachable by the executing servers 1 and 2,

```
$url= "http://www.lhp.layalisolutions.com"; 

if (isDomainAvailible($url))
       {
               echo $url." is up and running!";
       }
       else
       {
               echo $url." is not reachable!";
       }

       //returns true, if domain is availible, false if not
       function isDomainAvailible($domain)
       {
               //check, if a valid url is provided
               if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
               {
                       return false;
               }

               //initialize curl
               $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
               curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
               curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
               curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
               curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

               //get answer
               $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

               curl_close($curlInit);

               if ($response) return true;

               return false;
       }
```

executing this script on server 1 yield server 3 is up and running!
http://hmmosoft.com/wbsrvs/WEbSrvcTest.php

executing this script on server 2 yield server 3 is not reachable!
http://www.layaligroup.com/imgOGs/WEbSrvcTest.php

What could possibly cause this script to yield different results on these two diefferent servers? is there a way to determine if it's a server 2 or server 3 issue?

This is not a curl related issue, as even the simple `file_get_contents` function fails to retrieve any response from server 3 when running on server 2, and no matter what method I use on server 2, I always fail to get any response from server 3.

**EDIT**
The script was runnig fine on both server 1 and 2, and this problem recently apeared from nowhere!

Comment: I suggest you simply check the network topology directly, so whether you can or can not reach the systems by means of command line utilities. Typically `telnet`. That is a very direct and clear test giving you a clear response or error message. Nothing you have to _guess_ the actual situation afterwards.

Comment: Try to check curl is enabled in php.ini .

Comment: @arkascha thx, I'll see wht I can do